# Document Number Evaluated Improperly Due to String Compare

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq

I have a list of document numbers to be evaluated.  This list is very large and I would rather not cast all document numbers to an int because they can also contain letters.  Here is a sample list of numbers.

```
1070
1071
1072
1073
1074
1075
1076
1077
1078
CO1089
CO1099
CO2000
```

These numbers are contained in objects in C# and I run Linq to return a list of objects in a Range.  Here is my linq code.

```
results = from row in MyObjectList.AsQueryable<MyObject>()
          where String.Compare(row.Header.DocNumber, _sDocumentStartNumber) >= 0 
          && String.Compare(row.Header.DocNumber, _sDocumentEndNumber) <= 0
          select row;
```

If I have a range of 
**From:**  1
**To:**      10000

A user would expect to get back all of the numeric numbered transactions within that range.  However, since i am comparing strings I get back no results.

I could detect that my to and from values are numeric and then evaluate only transactions with numbers and use a linq statement based on that (or edit the linq statement to do the conversion and comparisons), but I am concerned with performance at this point since the lists can be rather large when returning.

I am open to suggestions here and know that there may be many paths that all lead to the same result.  My key concern in this is ***performance***.  Remember that I could be performing this action on very large sets of data and I need the results returned in a reasonable amount of time.

Thank you in advance for any and all suggestions.

~~~ EDIT ~~~

### Additional Information

The objects that I am leveraging is Intuit IPP SDK objects for QuickBooks Online.  I am querying intuit for documents (such as invoices) and need to sort on the document numbers.  Intuit does not do this on their server side so I have to do this on my side.  Depending on what the user enters for other search criteria I could end up with ALL of their documents in a returned List.

Comment: How large is "very large"? I would suggest getting the code working first in the simplest fashion, then testing it for performance, rather than assuming that will be too slow. (Also, why are you using `AsQueryable`?) And should "CO2000" be treated as 2000, or just not treated as a value?

Comment: Do you want to include the "alphanumeric" document numbers when selecting a range? I would suggest creating your own ```IComparer``` instead of using ```String.Compare```.

Comment: In this circumstance the document numbers with Alpha character in them would not be returned.
I am using AsQueryable because "MyObject" is really a list of SDK objects that I am leveraging to interact with another product.

Comment: A large number could easily exceed 100,000.  I do not have a hard number as to this depends on how many objects the user creates in the external package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own comparer, say `DocumentNumberWithinRangeComparer`:

```
public class DocumentNumberWithinRangeComparer
{
    public int? RangeFrom { get; set; }
    public int? RangeTo { get; set; }

    public DocumentNumberWithinRangeComparer(int? from, int? to)
    {
        RangeFrom = from;
        RangeTo = to;
    }

    public bool IncludeInResults(MyObject obj)
    {
        if (!RangeTo.HasValue || !RangeFrom.HasValue)
            return true;

        int docnumber;
        if (!Int32.TryParse(obj.Header.DocNumber, out docnumber))
            return false;

        return docnumber >= RangeFrom.Value && docnumber <= RangeTo.Value;
    }
}
```

Then create an instance of it and use that to filter:

```
var comparer = new DocumentNumberWithinRangeComparer(0,100);
var results = from row in MyObjectList.AsQueryable<MyObject>()
              where comparer.IncludeInResults(row)
              select row;
```

If you want faster comparing, you should pre-process your "DocNumber" to be integers, but this only makes sense if you process the list of documents once and then query it multiple times.

---

A simple solution for pre-processing would be to create a `Dictionary<string, int>` from `Header.DocNumber` string value and the parsed number value. For values that dont parse you could use something like `-1`, `Int32.MinValue`, or make a more advanced parser that can deal with non-numeric values.

Once you have the dictionary you could query like this...

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>(); // Fill this...
var results = from row in MyObjectList.AsQueryable<MyObject>()
              where dictionary[row.Header.DocNumber] >= _sDocumentStartNumber &&
                    dictionary[row.Header.DocNumber] <= _sDocumentEndNumber 
              select row;
```

It will take some extra time to set up this dictionary, but it will pay back if you query the same document set multiple times.

Comment: I would love to have the list pre-processed. That would make things so much easier.  Maybe with v3 of intuit's IPP due out later this year they will include additional filtering so that I do not have to do all of this.  Thanks for the response.  I will run some tests with our sample data and see how they compare with performance.

Comment: I ended up using a comparer class like you suggested.  I did not do the dictionary route because I would only pass over the data once (though I have dictionaries all through this program for the re-used data.  Less calls to the cloud the better).  The comparer approach did not have any noticeable impact on performance and may have actually increased performance when users search using only numbers since I added in a check for that to simplify processing.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the range, left-pad the starting number with spaces so that it's the same length as the ending number. So in your example, your ending number is "10000". So make your starting number "*_*_1" (that is, 4 spaces and then a 1).

When comparing, left-pad the document number before comparing. So:

```
string paddedStart = _sDocumentStartNumber.PadLeft(_sDocumentEndNumber.Length);
string padded;
results = from row in MyObjectList.AsQueryable<MyObject>()
      let padded = row.Header.DocNumber.PadLeft(paddedStart.Length)
      where String.Compare(padded, paddedStart) >= 0 
          && String.Compare(padded, _sDocumentEndNumber) <= 0
      select row;
```